# User Input to determine the length of an array in Java

Tags: java

I am currently taking an intro to java class at my school due to my growing interest in programming.

I am to create a program that takes user input for a min and max integer. I am also to take user input for the size of the array as well as whether or not the user would like both the sorted and unsorted lists printed out.

After I collect this information, I need to generate random values within the given min/max range and sort those values(I had no problem completing these steps).

My code:

```
//Third Project by John Mitchell
package thirdProject;

//Imported library
import java.util.*;

//First class 
public class thirdProject {

    //Created scanner and random class as well as variables

    public static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static Random rand = new Random();
    public static int min, max, rand_num, sum, total, temp,  i, j;
    public static boolean sorted;
    public static int[] values = new int[]; 

    //Allowing for the average output to be of type double
    public static double average;

        //Main method
        public static void main(String[] args) {

            //Prompt user to enter minimum value to be sorted
            System.out.println("Please enter a minimum value: ");
            min = scan.nextInt();

            //Prompt user to enter maximum value to be sorted
            System.out.println("\nPlease enter a maximum value: ");
            max = scan.nextInt();

            //Prompt user to enter total number of values to be sorted
            System.out.println("\nPlease enter the number of values that you would like sorted: ");
            total = scan.nextInt();


            //Prompt the user whether or not they would like both lists
            System.out.println("\nWould you like to see both the sorted and unsorted lists? Please enter 'True' for yes or 'False' for no.");
            sorted = scan.nextBoolean();

            //Prints lists that were generated
                if (sorted == true) {

                gen_random_val();
                System.out.println("\nThe unsorted list is: " + Arrays.toString(values) + ".");
                sort_values();
                System.out.println("\nThe sorted list is: " + Arrays.toString(values) + ".");

                } else {

                gen_random_val();
                sort_values();
                System.out.println("\nThe sorted list is: " + Arrays.toString(values) + ".");

                }

        }

        //Second method
        public static void gen_random_val() {

            //For loop that generates values within the range of values given
            for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {

            values[i] = rand_num = Math.abs(rand.nextInt(max) % (max - min + 1) + min);
            sum = sum + values[i];
            average = (sum*1.0) / values.length;

            }
        }

        //Third method
        public static void sort_values() {

            //For loop that sorts values 
            for(i=0; i<(total-1); i++) {

               for(j=0; j<(total-i-1); j++) {

                  if(values[j] > values[j+1]) {

                       temp = values[j];
                       values[j] = values[j+1];
                       values[j+1] = temp;

                  }
               }
            }
        }
    }
```

Currently, the hard codes length of 10 values in the array works fine as I have recycled part of my code from a previous project. I am looking for guidance on how to simply make the size determined by user input.

Thank you.

Comment: Your requirement (whatever you have posted) doesn't ask you find the number of values that the user would like sorted. Rephrase `Please enter the number of values that you would like sorted` to `Please enter the number of values that you would like between min and max` to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example you can do this:

```
        //Prompt user to enter total number of values to be sorted
        System.out.println("\nPlease enter the number of values that you would like sorted: ");
        total = scan.nextInt();
        values = new int[total];
```

You don't have to give values to variables when you declare them.

Comment: Thanks very much Joni. Super quick and correct response. Funny thing is that I tried this method however I forgot to adjust the global declaration and so I am assuming that is why it did not work before. Thanks again. Hopefully this will help someone in the future!